# Is there an iOS sliding menu controller working like UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I found some iOS sliding menu controllers (like Path 2.0 , Facebook iOS), such as ViewDeck https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck, ECSlidingViewController https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController. But they does not work like UITabbar Controler.

I want to make left side menu controller work like UITabbar, and it can kepp state for each controller for every mene item. It should not create a new controller when I tap a menu item. When I tap a menu item to display a controller (as "controller a") and scroll to someplace, then I switch to another menu item, and switch back to "controller a", it should show me 'controller a' display without changed, just like a tap a UITabbar item.

Thank you.

Comment: Go ahead and create your own... and please post on Github :D

Comment: This may help you:

https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu

Comment: I am trying to do the same. I do not think SASlidemenu is working in the same way. when i come to the previous tab it shows the first view controller again. am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below link might help you :

https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu

Comment: How you solve this? Because I am facing the same issue

Comment: How can I take TabBar in it?

Answer (score 0):

I use ViewDeck, but I do not have the problem you mentioned. The menu calls the main view to perform a transition, not to instantiate a new view. Therefore, I can implement a back option on the menu to return to the original view in the same state as it was left.

Comment: Thanks. I want a directly way to do this. As @Unnati commented, github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu is perfect for my need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation. It's a subclass of a UINavigationController, and very easy to use.

https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu