# Implementing facebook app slide menu in TabBarItem iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, uitabbaritem

I am a student and am trying to implement facebook app slide menu in my iOS app. Currently, I have it implemented using UIBarButtonItem, using SWRevealViewController API as explained in [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/).
I have been researching on how to implement this using UITabBarItem instead, but have no luck finding it (I have been looking to other stackoverflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392580/is-there-an-ios-sliding-menu-controller-working-like-uitabbarcontroller). Most of the discussion is talking about implementing it for UIBarButtonItem instead of UITabBarItem. I tried to modify and play around my code right now, but it's not showing any success.
Basically I want the menu to be one of the tab items on the tab bar, instead of menubar.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you should assign `revealToggle:` when user selects `UItabBarItem` with given index. Let's say you have 4 controllers hooked to `UItabBarViewController` and you want the first one to be "menu". Then in `MyTabBarController` you should implement something like this:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
  if ([tabBar.items indexOfObject:item] == INDEX_OF_MENU) {
      [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
  }
}
```

This way if "menu" `tabbarItem` is selected you call `revealViewController` to slide. This is what you wanted?

Comment: eventually, you can in `viewWillAppear` check if currently menu is selected and do the same